# TFRecord IO slower than python hdf5 reader, how do I improve its speed?

Tags: tensorflow, hdf5, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord

I was following the official TF giude to use the `tf.data.Dataset` API for building data pipeline, but I found it ~2 times slower than my python data pipeline using hdf5.

### Here's my experiment result:

```
TFRecordDataset: 660 thousand samples/second 
hdf5 reader + feed_dict to placeholder: 1.1 million samples/second
```

My experiment setting is:
    - batch size=1000,
    - print log every 10 million samples to show the time,
    - run a **fake model** that only takes data as input and do not compute anything.

what's worse is that when I set batch size=10000, it becomes:

```
TFRecordDataset: 760 thousand samples/second 
hdf5 reader + feed_dict to placeholder: 2.1 million samples/second
```

### Here's my code for reading tfrecord

```py
def parse_tfrecord_batch(record_batch):
    FEATURE_LEN = 29
    dics = {
        'label': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64),
        'feature_id': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=(FEATURE_LEN,), dtype=tf.int64),
        'feature_val': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=(FEATURE_LEN,), dtype=tf.float32)
    }
    parsed_example = tf.parse_example(record_batch, dics)
    return parsed_example['feature_id'], parsed_example['feature_val'], parsed_example['label']

class fakeModel:
    def __init__(self, train_filenames):
        self.graph = tf.Graph()
        with self.graph.as_default():
            dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(train_filenames)
            dataset = dataset.repeat()
            dataset = dataset.batch(1000)
            dataset = dataset.map(parse_tfrecord_batch, num_parallel_calls=1)
            dataset = dataset.prefetch(1000)
            self.iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
            self.id, self.wt, self.label = self.iterator.get_next()

            self.train_preds = tf.identity(self.lbl_hldr)
```

I've tune the `num_parallel_calls` to 2, 10. Not working.

I've also tuned the `prefetch(n)` from 1 to 1000, which has little improvement.

My question is:
Is there any way to improve my tfrecord data pipeline? Am I missing something in my code?

Appreciate it for any help.

Comment: Why bother benchmarking a no-op model that does no computation?  Doesn't a real-world application's actual computation dwarf the dummy no-op time?  How long does your real code take to run in either of these systems?

Comment: @John Zwinck 1. Because when I train my DL model on GPU, the utility is below 50%. I guess the GPU is not fully utilized and the speed of the data pipeline could be a important factor, so I tested both methods. 2. Actually, both methods takes nearly same time during training DL model, showing similar GPU utility. so maybe the low utility is not brought by the data pipeline.